# WPF zoom canvas and maintain scroll position

Tags: wpf, scroll, canvas

I have a Canvas element, contained within a ScrollViewer, which I'm zooming using ScaleTransform. However, I want to be able to keep the scroll position of the viewer focused on the same part of the canvas after the zoom operation has finished. Currently when I zoom the canvas the scroll position of the viewer stays where it was and the place the user was viewing is lost.

I'm still learning WPF, and I've been going backwards and forwards a bit on this, but I can't figure out a nice XAML based way to accomplish what I want.

Here is the kind of code I'm using...

```
<Grid>
    <ScrollViewer Name="TrackScrollViewer" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <Canvas Width="2560" Height="2560" Name="TrackCanvas">
            <Canvas.LayoutTransform>
                <ScaleTransform ScaleX="{Binding ElementName=ZoomSlider, Path=Value}" 
                                ScaleY="{Binding ElementName=ZoomSlider, Path=Value}"/>
            </Canvas.LayoutTransform>

            <!-- Some complex geometry describing a motor racing circuit -->

        </Canvas>
    </ScrollViewer>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="8" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
        <Slider Name="ZoomSlider" Width="80" Minimum="0.1" Maximum="10" Value="1"/>
        <TextBlock Margin="4,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding ElementName=ZoomSlider, Path=Value, StringFormat=F1}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a purely XAML way of doing it, but there is a very nice piece of work on Joeyw's blog titled [Pan and Zoom (DeepZoom style) in WPF](http://blogs.windowsclient.net/joeyw/archive/2008/08/05/pan-and-zoom-deepzoom-style-in-wpf.aspx) with links to the source. He has taken some inspiration from DeepZoom and it gives you smooth/animated panning and zooming of content. And if you're using WPF 4 you could probably modify it a little to add some easing functions to the animations to give it an even nicer feel.

Comment: The above link gives lots of detail, but the download has been moved to a link from this page: http://blogs.windowsclient.net/joeyw/archive/2009/06/02/pan-and-zoom-updated.aspx

Comment: I was interested to read up on this but both of the links are broken. I did find an article on CodeProject (http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/DeepZoom.aspx) though.